# Programmatically open a route with state in react

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I have two types of item, one of which can contain data similar to the other.

Currently when form is used to save an item it saves it then uses `browserHistory.push` to show the next page.

But I wish add a button that will

1. save the currently item
2. redirect them to the form to add the other item type,
3. partially fill out this form with the data from the first item.

Is there a way to do this using react and not using local storage or session variables?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) (or other Flux based libraries) to store data between components and routes, avoiding the excessive prop nesting.

Answer (score 0):

`browserHistory.push` *won't work*. It only moves you to a certain location but it doesn't update the application state. You need to update application state, which then will reflect into location update, but not in the opposite direction. Keep in mind that, in React, data comes first, and its representation, even though mutable, doesn't change the data back. The same applies to the location.

To make the redirect alone work, I'd recommend wrapping your component into [`withRouter` higher-order component](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#withroutercomponent-options).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => this.props.router.push('/new-location')}>
          Click me to go to /new-location
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But if you need to pass data from one component to another, and the two aren't in hierarchy, I'd agree with Alomsimoy and recommend using Redux. But if, for some reason, it's not an option, you can store this data in a component that is parent to both forms:

```
class FormA extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={() => this.props.onSubmit()}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.props.inputA}
          onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChangeA(event)} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

class FormB extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={() => this.props.onSubmit()}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.props.inputB}
          onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChangeB(event)} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

while their parent would rule the location and state updates:

```
class Forms extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
  }

  handleChange(name, value) {
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  renderForm() {
    const {
      params: {
        stepId
      }
    } = this.props;

    if (stepId === 'step-a') { // <- will be returned for location /form/step-a
      return (
        <FormA
          inputA={this.state.inputA}
          handleChangeA={(event) => this.handleChange('inputA', event.target.value)}
          onSubmit={() => this.props.router.push('/form/step-b')} />
      );
    } else if (stepId === 'step-b') { // <- will be returned for location /form/step-b
      return (
        <FormB
          inputB={this.state.inputB}
          handleChangeB={{(event) => this.handleChange('inputA', event.target.value)} />
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {
      children
    } = this.props;

    console.log(this.state); // track changes

    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderForm()}
        <button
          onClick={() => this.props.router.push('/new-location')}>
          Click me to go to /new-location
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Forms);
```

so the route for them would look like

```
<Route path="form/:stepId" component={Forms} />
```